# Replace each elements of a list by another iterating each one of them

Tags: python, list, loops, luhn

I'm using luhn algorithm to check credit card numbers (Visa or MasterCard).
I have two list:

1. `credit_card_number_checked = [random numbers generated]` : credit card numbers checked by luhn algorithm
2. `check_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

   When the luhn algorithm tells me:

   > invalid credit card number

Then I want to replace each number of the first list with the second list iterating until I get **valid number** kinda like a chronometer from right to left.

**Example:**
Input:

```
credit_card_number_checked = ['5', '4', '4', '4', '6', '5', '1', '2', '8', '0', '9', '5', '8', '6
', '7', '0']
check_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Output:

```
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 7 0
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 7 1
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 7 2
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 7 3...

5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 1 0
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 2 0
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 6 3 0...

5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 1 7 0
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 2 7 0
5 4 4 4 6 5 1 2 8 0 9 5 8 3 7 0...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're mixing strings and its here, but it would probably be better to choose on an be consistent.

That said...you can make a generator that will produce the iterations in this order with something like:

```
def makeIters(cc, n):
    for i in range(len(cc) - 1, -1, -1):
        yield from (cc[:i] + [str(num)] + cc[i+1:] for num in n)
```

With that you can lazily iterate over the numbers until you find one that passes your test:

```
cc = ['5', '4', '4', '4', '6', '5', '1', '2', '8', '0', '9', '5', '8', '6', '7', '0']
n = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for cc in  makeIters(cc, n): 
    if luhn(cc):  # your luhn test that returns true with a good number
        print(cc)
        break
```

You could use the same generator to get a list of all good numbers using `filter()`:

```
list(filter(luhn, makeIters(cc, n)))
```